# Spelling of צֹנַאֲכֶם

Tags: grammar-dikduk, mattos

In Parshas Mattos, [32:24](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.32.24), there is an unusual construction for the plural possessive "your sheep" - 
בְּנוּ-לָכֶם עָרִים לְטַפְּכֶם, וּגְדֵרֹת לְצֹנַאֲכֶם; וְהַיֹּצֵא מִפִּיכֶם, תַּעֲשׂוּ.

What is the rule for this construction? Does it have a name, and are there any similar words in the Tanach?

Comment: What is unusual about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my Concordance, there are two similar words for “sheep”.

They are
צאן   and צֹנֶה.

"Your sheep" will form as צאנכם and צנאכם respectively.

(The difference is in the position of the aleph).

The normal spelling is צאן and there are many occurrences in Tanakh.

צאנכם occurs in Ex 10:24, Ex 12:32 and 1Shmuel 8:17.

צֹנֶה occurs once in Psalms 8:8 and as צנאכם in Num 32:24 as you quoted.

So it seems not to be a construction but two different words. I am not competent to tell if this occurs anywhere else.

After I wrote the above, I saw the Rashi on [Num 32:24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9960#showrashi=true) which is the source for the information in the Concordance.

> or your sheep: Heb. לְצֹנַאֲכֶם. This word is cognate with,“Flocks
>   (צֹנֶה) and cattle, all of them” (Ps. 8:8), in which there is no א
>   separating the נ from the צ. The א that appears here after the נ [in
>   the word לְצֹנַאֲכֶם is in place of the ה in the word צֹנֶה. I learned
>   this from the commentary of R. Moshe Hadarshan [the preacher].

Comment: I wanted to check Ibn Ezra but my Chumash was not handy, so I settled for checking the Minchas Shai in my tikkun, who says nothing. One day I will learn to check the basics before asking.